# Why itertools.groupby() doesn't work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, group-by, python-itertools

I've checked some topics about `groupby()` but I don't get what's wrong with my example:

```
students = [{'name': 'Paul',    'mail': '@gmail.com'},
            {'name': 'Tom',     'mail': '@yahoo.com'},
            {'name': 'Jim',     'mail': 'gmail.com'},
            {'name': 'Jules',   'mail': '@something.com'},
            {'name': 'Gregory', 'mail': '@gmail.com'},
            {'name': 'Kathrin', 'mail': '@something.com'}]

key_func = lambda student: student['mail']

for key, group in itertools.groupby(students, key=key_func):
    print(key)
    print(list(group))
```

This prints each student separately. Why I don't get only 3 groups: `@gmail.com`, `@yahoo.com` and `@something.com`?

Comment: Jim's email is `gmail.com` instead of `@gmail.com` like the others. Typo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters, some of the mails are `gmail.com` and some are `@gmail.com` which is why they are treated as separate groups.

`groupby` also expects the data to be pre-sorted by the same `key` function, which explains why you get `@something.com` twice.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> ... Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function. ...

```
students = [{'name': 'Paul', 'mail': '@gmail.com'}, {'name': 'Tom', 'mail': '@yahoo.com'},
            {'name': 'Jim', 'mail': 'gmail.com'}, {'name': 'Jules', 'mail': '@something.com'},
            {'name': 'Gregory', 'mail': '@gmail.com'}, {'name': 'Kathrin', 'mail': '@something.com'}]

key_func = lambda student: student['mail']

students.sort(key=key_func)
# sorting by same key function we later use with groupby

for key, group in itertools.groupby(students, key=key_func):
    print(key)
    print(list(group))

#  @gmail.com
#  [{'name': 'Paul', 'mail': '@gmail.com'}, {'name': 'Gregory', 'mail': '@gmail.com'}]
#  @something.com
#  [{'name': 'Jules', 'mail': '@something.com'}, {'name': 'Kathrin', 'mail': '@something.com'}]
#  @yahoo.com
#  [{'name': 'Tom', 'mail': '@yahoo.com'}]
#  gmail.com
#  [{'name': 'Jim', 'mail': 'gmail.com'}]
```

After fixing both sorting and `gmail.com`/`@gmail.com` we get the expected output:

```
import itertools

students = [{'name': 'Paul', 'mail': '@gmail.com'}, {'name': 'Tom', 'mail': '@yahoo.com'},
            {'name': 'Jim', 'mail': '@gmail.com'}, {'name': 'Jules', 'mail': '@something.com'},
            {'name': 'Gregory', 'mail': '@gmail.com'}, {'name': 'Kathrin', 'mail': '@something.com'}]

key_func = lambda student: student['mail']

students.sort(key=key_func)

for key, group in itertools.groupby(students, key=key_func):
    print(key)
    print(list(group))

#  @gmail.com
#  [{'mail': '@gmail.com', 'name': 'Paul'},
#   {'mail': '@gmail.com', 'name': 'Jim'},
#   {'mail': '@gmail.com', 'name': 'Gregory'}]
#  @something.com
#  [{'mail': '@something.com', 'name': 'Jules'},
#   {'mail': '@something.com', 'name': 'Kathrin'}]
#  @yahoo.com
#  [{'mail': '@yahoo.com', 'name': 'Tom'}]
```

Comment: Ok, I've read documentation and I saw that sequence must be ordered but I've gotten lost because of a dictionary cannot be sorted. I've created  a messy code.

Comment: @kviatek It is about ordering the *list* of dictionaries, not the dictionaries themselves.

Comment: I'm trying to edit the question into shape to be a more suitable duplicate target; would you mind if I change Jim's email from `gmail.com` to `@gmail.com` like the others? It's not really relevant to the question I think.

Comment: @Aran_Fey Yes, of course, I've seen that you've done it already but I response, anyway. DeepSpace Yes, I know but like I've said I was lost among all objects and I ended up trying to sort dictionaries what, obviously, was not wat has to be done. Now everything is clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

itertools uses the sort order of the data. Your list is not sorted.

So if you have ["gmail.com", "something.com", "gmail.com"] itertools will create three groups. This is different than the groupby in some functional languages (or Python pandas for that sake).

You need to sort the dict first.

```
import itertools

students = [{'name': 'Paul', 'mail': '@gmail.com'}, {'name': 'Tom',    'mail': '@yahoo.com'},
            {'name': 'Jim', 'mail': 'gmail.com'}, {'name': 'Jules', 'mail': '@something.com'},
            {'name': 'Gregory', 'mail': '@gmail.com'}, {'name': 'Kathrin', 'mail': '@something.com'}]


 for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(students, key=lambda x: x["mail"]), key=lambda student: student['mail']):
     print(key)
     print(list(group))

# @gmail.com
# [{'name': 'Paul', 'mail': '@gmail.com'}, {'name': 'Gregory', 'mail': '@gmail.com'}]
# @something.com
# [{'name': 'Jules', 'mail': '@something.com'}, {'name': 'Kathrin', 'mail': '@something.com'}]
# @yahoo.com
#[{'name': 'Tom', 'mail': '@yahoo.com'}]
#gmail.com
# [{'name': 'Jim', 'mail': 'gmail.com'}]
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but: this has nothing to do with the fact that dicts are unorderable, OP is grouping-by a *list* of dictionaries. You can see in my answer why it doesn't work as they expect

Comment: Thank you DeepSpace. Fixed.