# Using itertools groupby to find the group of all even numbers in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I am trying to understand the usefulness of the `itertools.groupby()` function and have created a rather naive use case. I have a list of numbers, and want to group them by oddness or evenness. Below is my code using `itertools.groupby()`:

```
for decision, group in groupby(range(2, 11), key=lambda x: x % 2 == 0): 
    ...:     print(decision, list(group))
```

And below is the output I get:

```
True [2]
False [3]
True [4]
False [5]
True [6]
False [7]
True [8]
False [9]
True [10]
```

Basically what I was expecting is something like where all the "True's" are grouped together and all the "False's" are grouped together.

Is this even possible with `groupby()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why itertools.groupby() doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50198597/why-itertools-groupby-doesnt-work)

Comment: Take a look at [how do i use pythons itertools groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-pythons-itertools-groupby).  You'll see some use cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. It explains things a lot more clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`groupby()` combines **consecutive values** where their key output is equal, giving you a shared iterator for each such group. It will not process the whole input in one go, it gives you the groups *as you iterate*.

For your example, the key changes for each value, and so the groups consist of a single value each; it starts with `2` and the key output is `True`, then next comes `3` and the key produces `False`. Because `True != False`, that's a new group. The next value `4` changes the key again, to `True`, so it's another group, etc.

What you want to do can't be done with `groupby()`; to sort values into buckets *across* the whole iterable, just use a dictionary:

```
grouped = {}
for value in range(2, 11):
    key = value % 2 == 0
    grouped.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

You could also sort your input first, with `sorted(range(2, 11), key=lambda x: x % 2 == 0)`, but *that's a waste of time*. Sorting is a more complex algorithm, taking O(n log n) ([*quasilinear*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Quasilinear_time)) time, whereas using a dictionary to group the values takes O(n) ([*linear*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linear_time)) time. That might not matter when you have just 9 elements, but when you have to process 1000 elements, sorting would increase the time taken by a factor of nearly 10, for 1 million elements, a factor of nearly 20, etc.